# Custom RKPathMatcher

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

Is it possible to plugin a custom RKPathMatcher implementation to support custom paths?

I am using the LinkedIn API which allows for choosing which fields to return in the response JSON. For example, the following returns just a connection's firstName and lastName fields (excluding a lot of other data):

`[api path]/people/~/connections:(fistName,lastName)`

I want to be able to use the same RKObjectMapping for a connection, but be able to match it if the path is slightly different. It may be, '/people/~/connections' to get all the connection fields. Or, as above, some variable number of fields specified, e.g: '/people/~/connections:(id,modified,phone).

Is this possible with a single response descriptor, something like:

```obj-c
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:connectionMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"people/~/connections" keyPath:@"values" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Comment: You would probably need to create your own fork of RestKit and SocKit. Or you could look at making a pull request with the changes to SocKit and try to get it fully incorporated

Comment: @wain that was my last option yes. customise it for my needs.